# In Javascript how do I initiate and draw a selection box on a <div> element for floating elements inside?

Tags: javascript, html, selection

In a pure Javascript project which uses a full-sized `<div>` element containing floating other `<div>` elements, I want to be able to select elements using both a `mousedown`-activated selection-rectangle and (not first priority) using `CTRL` + click to toggle selection for a single element.

There seems to be something already enabled (at least in Firefox) - there I can click and move the mouse and random elements get visibly selected. So maybe I've already accidentally deactivated/crippled a default setting on my site.. But since behavior differs from browser to browser I'd like to ask the general question:

In modern browsers/Javascript is there a built-in way to select visible elements inside a DOM using the mentioned gestures/controls?

Is there special terminology or a simple example I can use as a start for further research?